# Which species of centipede is this and is it dangerous to cats?

Tags: species-identification, arthropod

My cat was "playing" (aka torturing) with this centipede:

[image: Centipede]

I tried to measure its length with a measurement tape:

[image: centipede measurement]

Since I know some species of centipede can be poisonous, I tried to find if centipedes can be dangerous to a cat, but [the](https://www.thespruce.com/cats-and-insects-555032) [links](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskVet/comments/2dyb91/is_it_okay_for_my_cat_to_eat_house_centipedes/) [said](https://www.justanswer.com/pet-cat/0q3t2-centipede-bite-kill-cat.html) it depends of the species.

When the cat tried to catch it, the centipede ran fast to below the carpet or my slipper. Now, when I lift the carpet, it pretends to be dead, although in one occasion the arthropod moved its legs without changing position.

If it matters, I'm in Southern Brazil in a subtropical region and it's 01:30 AM. I don't think it bite my cat, since I'm not seeing any signals of health problems on the cat (also the anxiety of being forced out of my room so they can't interact until I solve the situation).

I think this animal is a [*Scolopendra*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scolopendra), known here as "Lacraia".

Comment: It looks *a lot* like a Chinese red head, but I'm not sure if they're found in Brazil..

Comment: The picture seems like this one, but it is from Tanzania (with invasive presence in Saint Helena, but not in Brazil): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scolopendra_morsitans

Comment: Also the Chinese red head is a subspecies of *Scolopendra subspinipes* species, which is present in South America:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scolopendra_subspinipes

Comment: Visually it seems a lot like a younger [Chinese red headed centipede](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_red-headed_centipede) since they average at 20 cm rather than 5-6, but it shouldn't exist here in Brazil. I tried finding a page in Portuguese but apparently there's only an English option.